# Blob storage id can not inserting to Azure SQL database through Azure function

Tags: azure, azure-sql-database, azure-blob-storage, azure-functions

I have created a function app and the purpose is to insert the blob storage text details into Azure database
"Title" column in created, the function call "BlobTriggerCSharp1" and created with c#

```
#r "System.Configuration"
#r "System.Data"
using System.Configuration;
using System.Data.SqlClient;
using System.Threading.Tasks;
using System;

public static void Run(Stream myBlob, string name, TraceWriter log)
{
    log.Info($"C# Blob trigger function Processed blob\n Name:{name} \n Size: {myBlob.Length} Bytes");
    string detail = ($"{name}");


    var str = ConfigurationManager.ConnectionStrings["sqldb_connection"].ConnectionString;
    using (SqlConnection conn = new SqlConnection(str))
    {
        conn.Open();
        var text = "INSERT INTO PhotoTable(ID,CreatedAt,UpdatedAt,IsDeleted, Url, Title)VALUES (284,SYSDATETIMEOFFSET(),SYSDATETIMEOFFSET(), 'true', 'yrhrh', {name})";

        using (SqlCommand cmd = new SqlCommand(text, conn))
        {
            // Execute the command and log the # rows affected.
            var rows = cmd.ExecuteNonQueryAsync();
            log.Info($"{rows} rows were updated");
        }
    }
}
```

so when the text blob uploads the function triggers but it doesn't enter the blob id in to the column in the Azure SQLdatabase ( database columns are defined in the query ID,CreatedAt,UpdatedAt,IsDeleted, Url, Title) as it shows above the parameter i am going to pass to the database is "{name}" ( because Name:{name} is the variable of id in the blob-storage) which is the Blob-storage unique id ( in other words need to transfer the {name} to the Title column in database) , i am so confused what i am missing and don't know my way of going to transfer is wrong or else the datatype is wrong, so confused and stuck, help will be greatly appreciate , thanks

Comment: I understood you are confused, but I don't understand 1) what's your desired outcome 2) what's your current problem. Please edit to make this more clear.

Comment: One thing is that your INSERT does not use string interpolation as you probably intended: `$"INSERT..."`. Though why use string interpolation? You should always parameterize the query to avoid injections.

Comment: @Mikhail,Thank you for the reply,1) the process what my app does is that when the user gives the text input ( example: Name) that text goes to the blob and it saves in the storage text blobs such as Name,Tasks, job number,my requirement is that i have a history page in my app where user can find the Jobs they enter with job-number, so blob storage is just store data and i thought of using a function to connect with AzSQL to store the uploading data in table and using another function to retrieve back to the app to show the history, but i m still stuck with first part , to blob data to database

Comment: @juunas, Thank you for the reply , but i have used to write php services to servers but this Azure concept is different so i don't know which sql statements i have to write to make an Insert statement with the jason parameters i am getting, if you have suggestions please let me know thanks,

Comment: Check @Mikhail's answer :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should change your INSERT statement to add parameters to it. Here is an example with `Name`:

```cs
var text = "INSERT INTO PhotoTable(ID,CreatedAt,UpdatedAt,IsDeleted, Url, Title) " +
           "VALUES (284,SYSDATETIMEOFFSET(),SYSDATETIMEOFFSET(), 'true', 'yrhrh', @Name)";

using (SqlCommand cmd = new SqlCommand(text, conn))
{
    cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@Name", name);

    // Execute the command and log the # rows affected.
    var rows = cmd.ExecuteNonQueryAsync();
    log.Info($"{rows} rows were updated");
}
```

Comment: your solution perfectly works for me, Thank you so much, have a sub question for the solution , now we are getting the unique ID of the blob storage , is their any way that i can insert the content of that blob storage to the sql table??  Example now the unique blobID contains the Name of the user inside but the table updates with the blobID only is their any way that i can enter the detail in the Name attribute of the blobstorage inside the SQL Name column??? ( by the way in my sql have columns such as ID,Name,url)

Comment: If you need to insert contents, you can change type of `myBlob` from `Stream` to `byte[]`, then add a column to the table, insert statement and parameters. I got lost in the second part of your second question... Just try things similar to what you already have working.

Comment: as you instructed i have change the Stream to byte[] as below

Comment: public static void Run(byte[] myBlob, string name, TraceWriter log) and i have kept the parameters as earlier, var text = "INSERT INTO PhotoTable(ID,CreatedAt,UpdatedAt,IsDeleted, Url, Title) " +
           "VALUES (555,SYSDATETIMEOFFSET(),SYSDATETIMEOFFSET(), 'true', 'yrhrh', @Name)";
        using (SqlCommand cmd = new SqlCommand(text, conn))
        {
            cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@Name", name);
            // Execute the command and log the # rows affected.
            var rows = cmd.ExecuteNonQueryAsync();
            log.Info($"{rows} rows were updated")

Comment: but the sql database columns are not updating the values inside

Comment: sorry if i not make the above question unclear i only chnage the parameter public static void Run(byte[] myBlob, string name, TraceWriter log) and kept the column names as before ( ID,CreatedAt,UpdatedAt,IsDeleted, Url, Title) and i wanted the "title" column to insert the blob contain details but its not updating ?? any idea ??